# IIS cannot connect to Sql Server - Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

Okay, I've read a bunch of the related questions on here, and been googling, and cannot figure this out.

One of our clients wants us to set their website up on a server, which is also running Sql Server and the site's database; that is, ***same box***.

The website is unable to connect to the database though, yielding the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I also checked the Windows Event Logs, to see if it gave any further information, but it simply restated the same message with no additional information.

The server is Windows Server 2008 Standard.
IIS is the included IIS version with that version of Windows.
Sql Server is Sql Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.
I have a data-access library I have written to connect to Sql Server.

- I have verified `Remote Connections` are on in Sql Server (though it's the same box).
- I have verified `SQL and Windows Authentication` is on to allow Sql logins.
- I have verified my connection string and data-access layer via a test windows app.
- I have used PortQryUI to verify the Sql Server is available.

I have also tried various variations on the connection string, such as:

- MYSERVER\INSTANCE
- localhost\INSTANCE
- 127.0.0.1\INSTANCE
- (local)\INSTANCE
- tcp:(local)\INSTANCE
- np:(local)\INSTANCE
- .\INSTANCE
- MY.PUB.IP.ADD\INSTANCE

So Sql Server seems to be set up properly.
My test Windows app works fine, confirming my connection string is correct and my data-access layer can connect.

It would seem that this is something to do with IIS specifically, and some setting in there must be blocking the connection.

**ADDITIONAL:**
Windows Firewall is not running.
Sql Browser Service is running.
All network protocols are enabled in the server configuration.

I am using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` object to build my connection string. To verify Sql authentication being used, I put out the ConnectionString being returned by the builder:

> Data Source="(local)\INSTANCE";Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword

Comment: Do you have Windows Firewall turned on? Is the SQL Browser service running? Did you verify that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled for this service in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: No, yes and yes. Firewall is not running, and browser and tcp/ip are both enabled.

Comment: Ok, and are you 100% this is a named instance, not the default instance?

Comment: Yes. It is definitely a named instance. As mentioned, the same exact connection info DOES work fine from a Windows app running on the server, ... it is only the IIS app that is having connection problems.

Comment: And what Windows account is IIS running as? Where exactly is the connection string stored, and how is IIS initiating the connection to SQL Server?

Comment: It might be useful to inject a try/catch where the connection is being instantiated, and log the connection string and credentials to a file. This might show you that the connection string and/or user account that's being used is not the one you think is being used.

Comment: The connection is established through my data-access library, which I also used in the Windows test app to eliminate that as a problem. As for the IIS account, IIS Admin service is running as `Local System`, and the w3p service is running as `Local System` also.

Comment: I think I can see where Aaron Bertrand is going. If your database connection string uses Windows Authentication, the default IIS App Pool Identity won't be able to connect to SQL Server until you grant it access.

Comment: Please see the additional update. I have verified that the connection string is *not* specifying integrated authentication.

Comment: Just to humor us, change IIS temporarily to run as a local administrator account that has been given explicit access to SQL Server.

Comment: Do I just need to change the IISAdmin service, or also the w3p service?

Comment: To note, this is also their PDC box (SMH), so there are no truly local accounts. I tried changing it to a domain admin account with admin rights in Sql, and it required stopping and restarting the service. When I tried to restart the IISADMIN service, it told me: `Error 1297: A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration.`